# How to open bootstrap datetimepicker on custom button click, but value should be save in hidden textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

On click of `ADD` button, datetimepicker should be opened and when value is selected from datetimepicker it should be saved in texbox `#myTextBox`.

```
<div>
    <input id="myTextBox" type="text" ng-model="c" data-provide="datepicker"/>
    <input type="button" data-provide="datepicker" class="btn btn-primary" name="" value="Add"/>
</div>
```

How to achieve the same ?

Comment: I don't know where to write the code, in angularjs controller or using jquery]

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#yourid" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#myTextBox" ).html(selectedDate);
        }
});
```

for this you should include datepicker.js in your html page

Comment: ``<link href="/Contents/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />``
    ``<script src="/Contents/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>``

I have already included above in my html page

Comment: onClose event is not firing

Comment: I am using bootstrap datepicker not jquery datepicker, so please make sure you are providing the solution in terms of bootstrap